# Youtube Video link on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, youtube

I am displaying a database from firebase and I want to replace the image with either a YouTube link or just display the video on the app. Also, I am using a card view for the recyclerview. How would I implement that if I want to save the link as "video" in my exercise database?
[image: This is the recyclerView of the database]

[image: database in firebase]

Comment: Are you asking [how to show a youtube video in an android app](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+how+to+show+a+youtube+video+in+android+app)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for show youtube video in your android app please see this library :
[android youtube player github](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player)

you can simply add video id to this view and it will show the video from youtube :

```
<com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        
        app:videoId="S0Q4gqBUs7c"
        app:autoPlay="true" />
```

Comment: how would I use it with a MyViewHolder? I tried "holder.youTubePlayerView.loadVideo(exercise.getVideo(), 0);" but the loadVideo() method doesn't load.

Comment: please send your adapter and item xml code