# How would I use YouTubePlayerView with holder to display in recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, youtube

I want to get the video ID from my database, use the string and load the YouTube video in the cardview. But I'm lost on how to load the video using the holder.

[image: I have the video ID stored as a string in my database]

[image: CardView]

This is my onBindViewHolder in my adapter class.

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

```
    Exercise exercise = list.get(position);
    holder.exerciseName.setText(exercise.getExerciseName());
    holder.muscleGroupName.setText(exercise.getMuscleGroupName());
    holder.equipmentName.setText(exercise.getEquipmentName());
    Glide.with(holder.imageView).load(exercise.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);

}
```

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

```
    public ImageView imageView;
    TextView exerciseName, muscleGroupName, equipmentName;
    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;


    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        exerciseName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exerciseNameInput);
        muscleGroupName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.muscleGroupNameInput);
        equipmentName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.equipmentNameInput);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageInput);
        youTubePlayerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.video);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything from the [how to show a youtube video in an android app](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+how+to+show+a+youtube+video+in+android+app) results I linked from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71326787/youtube-video-link-on-android-studio)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added the dependencies, but in my onBindViewHolder, I can't figure out how to display it.  I tried holder.youTubePlayerView.loadVideo(exercise.getVideo(), 0) but the loadVideo() method is not loading.